# Smoke Domains Piled Up

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

For some reason after baking all of my smoke domains pile up on one of the domains. When I try to move the domain, it displays the domain in the correct spot.
Should I have created one huge domain to include all smoke/fire emitters?
Does anyone know what I've done to cause this?

EDIT: Changing the Cache type to "Replay" reset the domains....Why doesn't it work for "Modular" Cache
[image]